# Need a copy group of records

Tags: cobol, mainframe

Input File 1 [VB 1504 Bytes]

HEADER REC 
 2000A..... 
 REC1.... 
 REC2.... 
 2300.... 
 REC3.... 
 REC4.... 
 . 
 . 
 RECN...... 
 2000A 
 REC1.... 
 REC2.... 
 2300.... 
 REC3.... 
 REC4.... 
 . 
 . 
 RECN...

FILE2 [10 Bytes FB] 
 1234567891 
 9876544211

I want to copy record where 10 BYtes key in File 2 match with 10 Bytes key present in record starting with 2300. Key position [15:10]

If key matches copy record starting from 2000A till next 2000A record.

Any suggestions ....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Save records 2000A to rec2. If the 2300 record has the rquired key write out the saved records, the 2300 record and process further records until the next 2000A. If no match then simply read records until next 2000A record and start saving again. Of course, tis assumes that your data set (not FILE if you are on ZOS) structure is as you specify - 2000A, rec1, rec2, 2300....

Comment: @gehbiszumeis - However, asking about an algorithm is permitted. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question appears to be about an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

you can try DFSORT to do it....see link below https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.icea100/ice2ca_Example_3_-_Create_files_with_matching_and_non-matching_records.htm

Comment: That solution is for an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you need records from the VB1504 file where the records are starting with 2300 and matching the key from FB10.
You are going to need DFSORT/ICETOOL join operation.
Assuming the given positions; FILE1 being FB10 and FILE2 being VB1504; the JCL along with the SYSIN card goes something like this -

```
//JOBNAME  JOB 'DFSORT JOIN',CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,
//         NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//*
//SORTJOIN EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//FILE1    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=FILE1
//FILE2    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=FILE2
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=OUTPUT.FILE,
//         DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),UNIT=SYSDA,
//         SPACE=(CYL,(10,10),RLSE),DCB=*.FILE2
//SYSIN    DD *
  JOINKEYS FILE=FILE1,FIELDS=(01,10,CH,A)
  JOINKEYS FILE=FILE2,FIELDS=(19,10,CH,A),
           INCLUDE=(05,04,ZD,EQ,2300)
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F2:01,1504)
  OPTION   COPY
/*
```

This will give you non-duplicate records from the VB1504 file where the records are starting with 2300 and matching the key.
If you want duplicate records, then change `OPTION COPY` to `OPTION EQUALS`

Comment: How does this _copy record[s] starting from 2000A till next 2000A record_?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
Open files.
Process header for 'File 1'.
Load 'File 2' into a 'lookup table'.
For each '2000A group' in 'File 1' until 'end of file'.  
    Set a 'record counter' to zero.  
    Load all records into a 'buffer table', until another '2000A' record
        or end of file is found, counting the number of records.  
    Locate the '2300' record in the 'buffer table'. (The location may be saved
        while loading the 'buffer table'.)  
    Search the 'lookup table' for a value matching the value in
        the '2300' record.  
    If a match is found.  
        Write the 'buffer table' to the output file.  
End of for each.
Close files.
```

---

Or, as NicC suggests,

**Method 2:**

```
Open files.
Process header for 'File 1'.
Load 'File 2' into a 'lookup table'.
For each '2000A group' in 'File 1' until 'end of file'.  
    Set the 'buffer table' 'record counter' to zero.  
    Load records into a 'buffer table', counting the number of records,
        until the '2300' record is found.  
    Search the 'lookup table' for a value matching the value in
        the '2300' record.  
    If a match is found.  
        Write the 'buffer table' to the output file.  
        Write the '2300' record to the output file.  
        Copy records from the input file to the output file until another
            '2000A' record is found or end of file.  
    Else.
        Skip records from 'File 1' until another '2000A' record is found
            or end of file.  
    End of if.  
End of for each.
Close files.
```

---

Which method to choose may depend on the number of records to be saved in the 'buffer table'. Method 1 uses two routines: `Load 'buffer table'` and `Write 'buffer table'`. Method 2 uses four routines: `Load 'buffer table'`, `Write 'buffer table'`, `Copy 'File 1'`, and `Skip 'File 1' records` (though `Copy 'File 1'` could have `'Skip flag'` to prevent writing the records). This is not much of a difference.